# Peer to peer data transfer via Wifi and/or Bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, wifi, gamekit

I am currently trying to develop an application that uses the device camera to record video. Currently i am using an Apple demo that gets the data incoming from the camera and display it in a layer. In a second phase i started documenting about how to transfer that data via Bluetooth and/or Wifi to an other iPhone (real time local streaming), but i am getting no information about whether this is possible or not. Some posts say that this is limited due to the limited maximum data transfer size over wifi or Bluetooth. Could anyone tell me if this is possible or not ? Could anyone give me an example ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can at least for WiFi.  With Bluetooth there may be some issue with bandwidth.  For [network library](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket), there is this excellent library with example that you can start with.  You will need to learn at your own pace.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This can be achieved via this network library. However i want to know if this can be also achieved via the GameKit Framework. As Apple mentioned in its docs, You can transfer data via GameKit over Wifi. However i want to know if the transfer rate is fast enough to transfer real time data. The application that i am working on does not use an intermediary server and does not need an internet connection. It is like the Skype application but with no internet connection. Can CocoaAsyncSocket perform this ? Thanks.

Comment: As of iOS SDK 5.0 Bonjour services over Bluetooth is no longer enable by default.  The WiTap sample app from Apple used to work with Bluetooth.  Here are there links that if you are interested in: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/WiTap/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1753/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011315
https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Intro_GCDAsyncSocket